# Facebook Graph api group members

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am designing a web site that connects with Facebook's api using javascript to retrieve information. I have requested for the user_groups permissions in my access token and I want to retrieve information about a group I am a member of. The api returns the array with the group members but the number of members is not the same as the one seen in my facebook account when i go to the group's page. I have tested the same scenario in the graph explorer in Facebook's website the result is same, different number of members ...

What could the problem be ??

Code like:

FB.api('/' + facebookID + '/members', function(response) { console.log(response); });

while having a token with 'user_groups' permissions.

Response returns data for 60 memebers, group has 80 members when i look from within facebook. I am a member of this group (not admin though)

Thanks a lot in advance for any comments...

Comment: Show some code and give more details...

Comment: Users that have disabled using of all apps in their settings are “invisible” to apps in every way. (And with the new v2.0 of the API, you will only get to see friends that are also using your app.)

Comment: Code example would be something like :
FB.api('/' + facebookID + '/members', function(response) { console.log(response); });

I am a member of the group I am querying about (not admin) and the response returns 3900 members, while the group has 4100 members. When I go to the group page from within Facebook, I see 4100, the api returns 3900 (approx.)

Comment: It does not return more than 5000..... :/

Comment: @user3619525 got some more information? I'm facing the same problem and have no clue, whats going on